# Has anyone ever successfully connected a MAC to an Azure P2S network gateway? None of the documentation works for me

Tags: macos, azure, openssl, vpn

Starting with an empty directory:

1. Generate CAroot private key

```
$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -out dcsAzureVPN.key 2048
```

2. Generate a CARoot certificate

```
$ openssl req -x509 -sha256 -new -key dcsAzureVPN.key -out dcsAzureVPN.cer -days 1825 -subj /CN="dcsAzureVPN"`
```

3. Successfully copied `dcsAzureVPN.cer` to VPN gateway and saved (see attached screenshot)
4. Generate Certificate Request (CSR)

```
$ openssl genrsa -out dcsAzureClientCert.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -out tjaClientCert.req -key dcsAzureClientCert.key -subj /CN="dcsAzureVPN"`
```

5. Generate signed Client Certificate from CSR

```
$ openssl x509 -req -sha256 -in tjaClientCert.req -out dcsAzureClientCert.cer -CAkey dcsAzureVPN.key -CA dcsAzureVPN.cer -days 1825 -CAcreateserial -CAserial serial 
Signature ok
    subject=/CN=dcsAzureVPN
```

6. Pack key and certificate in .pfx format

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out dcsAzureVPNClient.pfx -inkey dcsAzureClientCert.key -in dcsAzureClientCert.cer -certfile dcsAzureVPN.cer
```

7. Copy client cert to my Keychain
8. Make dcsAzure VPN a trusted cert.
9. Select dcsAzureVPN as the client certificate for my VPN connection
10. Try to connect. Connection fails with an error: User Authentication failed

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem.  It turns out the Local ID has to match the client certificate subject, not the name of your client certificate file.

Comment: As of a few months ago this no longer worked for me. And the workaround of selecting "None" and then selecting the certificate I am already using. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually configure the native IKEv2 VPN client on every Mac that will connect to Azure. You could use [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-configuration-azure-cert#installmac) to configure the native VPN client on Mac for certificate authentication.

Moreover, you could refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-configuration-azure-cert#installmac) to troubleshoot Point-to-Site VPN connections from Mac OS X VPN clients.

Additionally, no matter what client OS you want to connect from, you must always have a client certificate. You can generate a client certificate from either a root certificate that was generated using an Enterprise CA solution or a self-signed root certificate. See the [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site), [MakeCert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site-makecert), or [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site-linux) instructions for steps to generate a client certificate.

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you Nancy.  Yes that is correct.  I've been using those same documents as a guide.  Have you successfully created a self-signed root cert on Mac and established a P2S VPN connection to an Azure Network Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Whoever stumbles up on this solution: It is working if you change the Client certificate's subj from dcsAzureVPN to (for example) dcsAzureVPNSubj and use it in the connection tab for Local ID.

So instead of this:

```
openssl req -new -out tjaClientCert.req -key dcsAzureClientCert.key -subj /CN="dcsAzureVPN"
```

Use this:

```
openssl req -new -out tjaClientCert.req -key dcsAzureClientCert.key -subj /CN="dcsAzureVPNSubj"
```

and use the dcsAzureVPNSubj for Local id on the MacOS VPN connection tab.

Worked on the following machine:
20.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0:  root:«gibberish»/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
Big Sur version: 11.4